# WebAPI - Bind Datetime dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webapp2

I have a intranet application using WebAPi and I'm having trouble binding the DateTime value to my model. I need the following format dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:sss

**XHR Post Data**

- Start=14/12/2015 02:44:09
- End=14/12/2015 02:44:10
- X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest

**Config**

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

**Model Properties**

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
public DateTime Start { get; set; }

[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
public DateTime End { get; set; }
```

As you can see I've tried using a custom JSON converter on the properties.

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public CustomDateTimeConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
    }
}
```

The issue seems to be with the day or month being the other way round i.e MM/dd/yyyyhh:mm:ss.

Any ideas how I can get this binding in properly? Do I need a custom binder or JSON serializer?

Comment: Well you can start by using `HH` instead of `hh`... but it's not clear what's happening with the code that you've got. Any reason you don't want to use the ISO format to be unambiguous?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks I didn't notice the HH. I'm displaying the dates in a calendar application for an intranet solely based in the UK. ISO dates are great but they aren't UI friendly for the user. I could convert before making the requests but I wanted to explore this first.

Comment: But if the value is being returned by webapi, that means it's presumably not the presentation layer anyway... The presentation layer should control the display format, IMO.